# Keep 3 significant digits using fromatC

Tags: r, rounding

I tried for following vector of three numbers:

```
formatC(c(0.8999, 2.9999, 43.98), digit=3, format="fg", flag='#')
```

The correct answer should be: 
    [1] "0.900" " 3.00"  "  44.0"

But this is what I've got: [1] "0.900" " 3.0"  "  44.". It seems formatC has trouble rounding a series of largest decimal digits.

The following code returns correct results [1] "0.833" "2.33"  "43.3":

```
formatC(c(0.8333, 2.3333, 43.33), digit=3, format="fg", flag='#')
```

I hate to claim that I found a bug, but comparing the same coding on different numbers, the unwanted results shows formatC has some flaws.

Comment: Like `formatC(43.98, digit=1, width=2, format="f")` or am i missing something?

Comment: I am trying to keep 3 significant digits for a vector, with the following code:

Comment: When I execute your examples, I have the correct outputs, and not the incorrect ones as you do. Could you attach to your message the result of a `sessionInfo()`?

Comment: > formatC(c(0.8999, 2.9999, 43.98), digit=3, format="fg", flag='#')
[1] "0.900" " 3.0"  "  44."
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
>

Comment: My boss run the code  formatC(c(0.8999, 2.9999, 43.98), digit=3, format="fg", flag='#') and got the correct answer, I am confused now ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As MrFlick posted as a comment `formatC(43.98, digit=1, format="f")` is what you want. Maybe this piece of the help page about the width might help:

> the total field width; if both digits and width are unspecified, width
>   defaults to 1, otherwise to digits + 1. width = 0 will use width =
>   digits, width < 0 means left justify the number in this field

Comment: The `width = 2` argument isn't doing anything in this example.